# Rearrange Arrays To Be in Order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple arrays in which they "switch" values unexpectedly.

I have three numpy arrays that should be:

```
a=[1 2 3 4], b=[7 8 9 10], c=[11 12 13 14]
```

However, they are in the current format:

```
a=[1 2 9 10], b=[7 8 13 14], c=[11 12 3 4]
```

What code can write such that the arrays are in the order as above? Please note that I do not know the indices at which the "switch" occurs at.

Comment: How these arrays are obtained? Provide code of that part

Comment: can we merge the list, then sort and split into 3 equal parts? or split into four elements? would that work?

Comment: That would work as well! How could I do that?

Comment: really interesting answers below. please chose any that suits you and remember to mark as answered

Comment: In this specific example, `a,b,c = map(list, zip(*map(sorted, zip(a,b,c))))` would work but it may not generalize, depending on how your inputs can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need ordered values, you can first `concatenate` the three arrays and `sort` and then `reshape` to get individual arrays

```
a=np.array([1, 2, 9, 10])
b=np.array([7, 8, 13, 14])
c=np.array([11, 12, 3, 4])

a, b, c = np.sort(np.concatenate((a,b,c))).reshape((3, 4))
a, b, c
# (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([ 7,  8,  9, 10]), array([11, 12, 13, 14]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append all three lists together, sort them, and then resplit the list into 3 parts again using list comprehension

```
a=[1, 2, 9 ,10]
b=[7 ,8, 13, 14]
c=[11 ,12, 3, 4]

#Append elements and sort them together
li = sorted(a+b+c)

#Resplit the list into 3 parts
a, b, c = [li[idx:idx+4] for idx in range(0,len(li),4)]

print(a,b,c)
```

The output will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [7, 8, 9, 10] [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.concatenate()` and `numpy.reshape()`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1, 2, 9, 10]) 
b=np.array([7, 8, 13, 14])
c=np.array([11, 12, 3, 4])


main = np.concatenate((a, b, c))
main.sort()
a, b, c = main.reshape(3, 4)
print(a)   #[1 2 3 4]
print(b)   #[ 7  8  9 10]
print(c)   #[11 12 13 14]
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh. Oh yeah. did not see that.

Comment: You don't need flatten I think.  Check my answer

Comment: @Sheldore. Yep. Thanks. Numpy is full of awesome stuff

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list containing all elements, sort this list and split it up again:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 9, 10]
>>> b = [7, 8, 13, 14]
>>> c = [11, 12, 3, 4]
>>> s = sorted(a + b + c)
>>> a, b, c = s[:4], s[4:8], s[8:]
>>> a, b, c
([1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by merge all your arrays then be resizing the output:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,9,10])
b = numpy.array([7,8,13,14])
c = numpy.array([11,12,3,4])

# merge, sort and reshape your arrays
d = numpy.sort(numpy.concatenate((a, b, c))).reshape(3,4)

# asssign them back
a,b,c = d
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3@YoBNwkMYlpBXfgl4mKShrZIHiTpol8fm7a60MXAgTv3EeY8eNeWMtrgYwY32TAzgvtGR4qRZv6Q2OAN5ekpmPrVLnhF2aI8L6L@M0qUDbZYRXYAa2JvEFKtItdBNGmgYGD2U4TVklj3zahvfEPtnaZs3HKcE4JC0EKI4x7Al4a1gFJKY@8gD8aCIv1ihArrrI6FOLrMSeygPqBFKW8)